# Using arcpy.da.UpdateCursor to populate field with dictionary values

Tags: arcpy, cursor, dictionary

I want to populate a field, named FnotExist, with values from a dictionary. I want to check if the key of the dictionary matches the row value in field FI_PATH and if it does populate the corresponding row in FnotExist. The keys in the dictionary should match row values in FI_PATH because keys were created from this field. The code below is giving me the error:

> TypeError: value #1 - unsupported type: list

when it reaches the line cursor.updateRow(row)

```py
import arcpy

arcpy.env.workspace = r"C:\TestFolder"

dbf = "ProcessControlTable"

dbf1 = "APExistOnlyEdit.dbf"

myfield = "FI_PATH"


filepathlist2 =[row[0] for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(dbf1,myfield)]
#print(filepathlist2)

#Dictionary one holds field names that are within shapefile
d1 = {}

for thisFile in filepathlist2:
    ContainedFieldNames = [f.name.upper() for f in arcpy.ListFields(thisFile)]
    d1[thisFile] = ContainedFieldNames

print(d1)

#Dictionary two holds field names that are thought to be in shapefile
d2 = {}

with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(dbf1,[myfield,'AP_FIPS','AP_BLDGCOM','AP_TYPE','AP_STATUS','AP_ID','AP_HOUSENU','AP_HALFADD','AP_PREDIR','AP_PRETYPE','AP_STNAME','AP_SUFTYPE','AP_SUFDIR','AP_UNITTYP','AP_UNIT','AP_BUILDIN','AP_FULLADD','AP_CITY','AP_STATE','AP_ZIP']) as rows:
    for row in rows:    
        d2[row[0]] = [a.upper() for a in row[1:] if a.strip() != '']

print(d2)


#arcpy.AddField_management(dbf1,'APNOTEXIST','STRING')
##Gets the difference detween dictionary two and dictionary 1
##https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34298613/python-find-difference-between-two-dictionaries-containing-lists
diff = {}

for key in d1:
    diff[key] = list(set(d2[key])-set(d1.get(key,[])))
print(diff)



with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(dbf1, ['FI_PATH', 'FnotExist']) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        keyValue = row[0]
        if keyValue in diff:
            row[1] = diff[keyValue]
            cursor.updateRow(row)
```

Below is an example of the dictionary, named diff, that I'm using to update the field FnotExist.

```py
{'C:\\TestFolder\\Folder1\\A\\address_pt.shp': ['TYPEB', ' BUILDINGA'], 'C:\\TestFolder\\Folder1\\B\\ADDRESS_VALID_POINTS.shp': [' PRETYPEA'], 'C:\\TestFolder\\Folder1\\E\\Public_Safety_Addresses.shp': [' TYPEA']}
```

Below is a pic of the dbf table that I'm trying to update. The field FI_PATH was used to create the keys in the dictionary so keys should match values in row.
[image]

I'm not sure why I'm getting an error and after research I can't figure out how to structure the code within the UpdateCursor.

Comment: What type of field is `FnotExist`?  If I understand your example dictionary, you're trying to populate this field with a List (rather than a String of a list...)

Comment: I agree. Try converting to string: `row[1]=', '.join(diff[keyValue])`

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to populate the field `FnotExist` that accepts strings with a dictionary value that is a list of strings. @BERA Your suggestion worked. I replaced `row[1] = diff[keyValue]` with `row[1]=', '.join(diff[keyValue])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already commented and your error message suggests, you are trying to write lists (=list data type) to a string field. Convert the list to a comma seperated string with [join](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_join.asp):

```
row[1]=', '.join(diff[keyValue])
```